# How to append values to array in C language

Tags: c, arrays

given a set of 10 digit number i need to find how many times the index appears in the give number e.g
given `2 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0` as an array element the array index from 0-9 so i have something like

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 ---> input
00115558 -----> output
```

the first index 0 appear twice, the second index 1 appear twice, the third index 0 appear 0 times so it's ignore and so on so the outcome is `00115558` and now i need to rearrange the output such that 0 must not start so i need something like `10015558` 
i was able to get the initial output like `00115558`, but i need to save it into an array so i can loop through the array and check for value greater than 0 and swap the position.

```
int main() {
   int i,j,len;
   int array[10],output[10];
   printf("Enter 10 digit number separated by space: \n");
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    if(array[i] != 0)
    {

        for(j=0; j<array[i]; j++)
           //output[j] = i;
           printf("%d ", i);
    }

}
```

I tried to save the output into another array and i printed the array outside the loop to see the content but the result wasn't what i wanted. How can i save my value into the output[] array. thanks for any help

Comment: *...the result wasn't what i wanted."* - what *was* it then. Frankly, I don't understand why you need an *input* `array` in this *at all*. Start a counter at zero, and for each number N you read, emit that counter value N times to a target array, adjusting the write point with each char written. Then bump the counter and read the next N, etc. Handle your seemingly arbitrary no-leading-zero resolution after that (it is completely unclear how you get `10015558` from  `00115558`, but honestly, it probably doesn't matter at this point.)

Comment: @ WhozCraig thanks for your help, the result i got now from the code is 00115558 but what i wanted is i don't want the output to start with 0 for i have to swap the next element in the array that is not 0 for the first element so that's how i got.  10015558, but the issue is i can't acheive this

Comment: Well, that's just a straight up search and swap algorithm after generating your count-string. Given output array `a`, if `a[0]` is `0`, then walk down the array until you find a non `0` value, and swap it with `a[0]` (assuming you didn't hit eos first). That's it. And you still don't need an input array; just the output side.

Comment: @WhozCraig i understand your explanation and i had just the same idea with you but the output array was suppose to contain something like 00115558 before i can make any search and swap, but when i try to loop through it and print it what i got wasn't what i expected, so i think the problem is where i wanted to append those value to the output array and i asked how to append values to array

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() 
{
         int i,j,len;
         int array[10],output[10];
         printf("Enter 10 digit number separated by space: \n");
         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         scanf("%d", &array[i]);
         len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
         for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] != 0)
        {

        for(j=0; j<array[i]; j++)
           //output[j] = i;
           printf("%d ", i);
        }

}
}
```

Sir, i tried you exact code as above in "Dev c++". I get answer is `00115558`. I think your Code is absolute Right. change your IDE software or Update that.

Comment: thanks so much yes i know the answer is right but i want it in the format.. 10015558, such that i won't start the output with 0

Comment: ' len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
         for(i=0; i<len; i++) ' so change that value of i is 1 to get your desire